# Does draining a dataflow job that uses FILE_LOAD write method ensure that all elements are written?

Tags: dataflow

You are writing elements to bigquery in the following way:

```
pcoll.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
     .to(destination)
     .withSchema(tableSchema)
     .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)
     .withTriggeringFrequency(org.joda.time.Duration.standardMinutes(10))
     .withNumFileShards(10)
     .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
     .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

And drain the job either via the gcloud cli tool or the google cloud console, it seems that the job is considered "drained" almost instantly, even if the `withTriggeringFrequency` had just triggered before. Is the behaviour of the drain function such that it triggers all writes if any are pending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Dataflow immediately closes any in-process windows and fires all triggers.
Once Drain is triggered, the pipeline will stop accepting new inputs. The input watermark will be advanced to infinity. Elements already in the pipeline will continue to be processed. Drained jobs can safely be cancelled.When you issue the Drain command.

For reference see this doc from 
Google  Effects of draining a job [Effects of draining a job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/stopping-a-pipeline#drain)